# Indentation by using AST from external program

Tags: indentation

I'm pondering over doing indentation by using an AST created with an
external (non-emacs) tool. But so far I do not really know where to
start. Are there emacs packages which already did this? Any tips and hints
are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to implement the LSP (language Server protocol) and use lsp-mode in conjunction with this. lsp-mode brings support for many languages already, but I'm not sure, if the LSP interface supports indentation.

Answer (score 0):

There is [emacs-tree-sitter](https://github.com/ubolonton/emacs-tree-sitter), which is a package that uses [tree-sitter](https://tree-sitter.github.io/tree-sitter/) a parser generator tool that can be use to get a AST of some supported languages.
Also emacs-tree-sitter support the option of get the AST of some languages so you can manipulate it and get some info, the [documentation](https://ubolonton.github.io/emacs-tree-sitter/api/) is interesting.

Good luck!